# Making a new background layer from existing layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

In Photoshop I have Background layer, Layer 1 and Layer 2.
I wanted the picture to have a black background so I painted all of Layer 2 black.

But now it covers the other layers.

How do I get it to be the new background layer and not have it cover up the other layers?

Answer (score 1):

This will all take place in the Layers panel (usually located on the right-side of your workspace)

- Click and drag Layer 2 down to sit between Layer 1 and Background layer.
  As you move your layers up and down, you will see a thick line between each layer you pass.

  [image: layers panel movement]
- Right-click on Layer 2
- Select **Merge Down** from the properties menu
- Layer 2 will now be merged with the Background layer.

**Hint:** If you click the eyeball on the left of each layer, you will be able to hide it from view and see any layers below which may have been blocked from view.

Comment: What if I've already deleted background layer?